# Windows boot options menu error

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, boot-failure

I had windows 7 installed on my Laptop, I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 via Bootable CD for trial. I am still able to run Ubuntu Live through the CD, but I was unable to install.

The installation process got completed only after selecting a partition disk and making it "ext 2" type. However after installation I do not see any boot menu. I even tried windows repair, that does not seem to work though. Also, I am not able to see any of the disk partition when I want to reinstall windows in any of the 7 partitions.

How do I do that? I just gave a try on secondary laptop in order to make sure it works. I am not keen to have Ubuntu on this particular machine, I just want to have windows back without loss of any data. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you have the Windows 7 CD?

Comment: yes, I have a win-7 CD..

Comment: Do you want to keep Ubuntu?

Comment: No I dont want to keep Ubuntu, I'v mentioned that in the question also.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is Backup your Linux files, if you have any.  After that is done, boot with the Ubuntu live CD, and delete every Linux partition. Boot, swap, and any other partitions that you may have created.

The Linux partitions don’t have a file system associated with them, and can be identifyed by size or partition number.  Once you do that, GRUB is gone, and you need to restore the MBR(Master Boot Record).

You would now need to boot Boot from Windows CD/DVD and choose “Startup Repair” when it shows up.

[image]

If the Startup Repair option does not resolve the issue, choose Command Prompt and run the following two commands:

```
bootrec /fixmbr 

bootrec /fixboot
```

Remove the CD, restart your system, and you should be able to boot into your Windows installation. 
To re-claim the space that was used by Ubuntu, again use the Ubuntu live CD, run GParted, and re-size you partition with the empty space that was occupied by Ubuntu.

You said that you have the Windows CD, but just in case you don't have your Windows 7 CD, or you can't find it, you can download a Windows 7 Recovery Disc, you can download it.  Click the desired architecture:

[32-bit (x86)](http://freakshare.com/files/o2db6v0s/CyberNetNews.com_Windows_7_32-bit_Repair_Disc.iso.html)

[64-bit (x64)](http://freakshare.com/files/56apzmkl/CyberNetNews.com_Windows_7_64-bit_Repair_Disc.iso.html)

Comment: Hi, I tried doing that, but "bootrec /fixboot" does not work It gives an error message. Is there another way around??

Comment: Have you tried startup repair?

Comment: yes I did that, actually that was my first try. The thing is, windows CD cannot find the HDD on my Laptop, and i guess that is because I have changed the type to "ext 2" while installing Ubuntu, but I did not make all the partitions "ext 2" type.

Comment: Boot from the Live CD, do **sudo fdisk -l** and post the results.

Comment: [Results of sudo fdisk -l](https://plus.google.com/u/0/104713047638273347236/posts/5Q78CoDiYSG)